# Reactive Extension buffer from buffers

Tags: system.reactive, reactive

I'm capturing audio from the microphone and producing a byte array of a certain length X at every sample. Is it possible with Rx.NET to subscribe to the EventHandler and get notified every time the array accumulates to a certain size?

Basically I want to get this:

```
source events: [---][---][---][---][---][---][---]
target events:       [-----][-----][-----][-----][-----]
```

Where for example the source event produces a byte array with a length of 3200 bytes and the received wants buffers 4096 bytes long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easy. Just try this:

```
var source = Observable.Range(0, 100).Buffer(5)
var target = source.SelectMany(x => x).Buffer(7);
```

My `source` has a buffer length of `5` that gets converted to a buffer length of `7` in `target`.

Comment: Thanks! Any way for buffer to produce an array without the arrays being transformed to and from a list of bytes?

Comment: @PincoPallino - Yes, but it starts to get more complicated. Have you tried this code to see if is performant enough?

Comment: I did yes and it fits the purpose for now.